# Can you use a GATT Configuration Service to configure Kontakt BeaconPro Eddystone-UID values?

Tags: gatt, eddystone, kontakt.io, gattlib

Is it possible to write a linux application that can update the Namespace and Instance IDs on a Kontakt BeaconPro configured to broadcast Eddystone-UID Packets? I have used Gattlib to scan for Eddystone Devices and discover their services, but it doesn't seem like the Configuration Service is present (service UUID a3c87500-8ed3-4bdf-8a39-a01bebede295) per https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/configuration-service.

You can configure these values in the Kontakt Android app, but my guess is they are using a custom service for configuration? Does anyone have any experience here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read [this blog post](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/207445555) correctly, then Kontakt beacons with firmware version 4.0+ are **no longer configurable via a GATT service**.  Configuration instead requires the Kontakt SDK for iOS or Android which does not use a GATT service.

The beacons do not support the Eddystone Configuration GATT Service unless you [request custom firmware](https://developer.kontakt.io/hardware/packets/eddystone/).

Comment: Thanks again, @davidgyoung. That was my reading of it as well. Your quick and thorough responses are always appreciated!